# Has anyone modelled calcium oscillations using Matlab software?

Tags: biophysics, computational-model, calcium

I have been trying to model calcium oscillations using MatLab, but I cannot obtain the oscillation.

I created a function where I put all the equations and used ode15s to call the function.  I have listed the equations and the code.

Can anyone tell me why I am not obtaining the oscillations?

**These are the equations along with the codes:**
[image]

```
r(:,3) = ( (((.029*0.13*1.049 + .21.*.5.*.144).*initi(:,1)) ./  (.144.*1.049.*(.5+ .13)) ) .*( 1- initi(:,3)) ) - (( (.21 *.5 + .029 *.9434) ./ (.5 +.9434) ).*initi(:,3));
```

> The values of the upper case Ks are obtained as follows:

[image]

> and the value of p is 0.5

[image]

```
a(:,1) = power (( (.5 .* initi(:,1) .*(1 - initi(:,3))) ./ ((.5 + .13 ).*(initi(:,1) + .0823)) ),3); % p_o
```

[image]

> Jserca is directly substituted in the equation shown below

[image]

```
r(:,1) = (( 1.11.*  a(:,1) + .02 ) .* (  initi(:,2) - initi(:,1) ) ) -( .9 .*  power(initi(:,1),2)) ./ ( power(.1,2) + power(initi(:,1),2) );
```

[image]

```
 r(:,2) = - r(:,1) .*5.5; % Ce
```

> **The constants are shown here:**

[image]

[image]

> **And this is the desired result:**

[image]

> **But I obtain this!**

[image]

> **And this is my code:**

```
function[t, initi, r,a]= deyoung()
clear all;
clc; 
close all;


%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Initial conditions
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
initi(:,1) = 0;  %  C  
initi(:,2) = .9; %  y
initi(:,3) = .5; %  Ce


%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ODEs
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
icon=initi; 

tspan=[0 100];

options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-08, 'AbsTol', 1e-08);

[t,initi] = ode15s(@(t,initi) oper(t,initi),tspan,icon, options );

[r,a] = oper(t,initi);

figure();
plot(t,initi(:,1),t,initi(:,3));

end

function [r,a]=oper(t,initi)

    initiSize = size(initi);

    initiColumnCount = initiSize(2);

    if ( initiColumnCount == 1)
        initi = initi';
        a = zeros(1,1); 
    else
        initiRowCount = initiSize(1);
        a = zeros(initiRowCount, 1);
        r = zeros(initiRowCount, initiColumnCount);
    end


    % y
    r(:,3) = ( (((.029*0.13*1.049 + .21.*.5.*.144).*initi(:,1)) ./  (.144.*1.049.*(.5+ .13)) ) .*( 1- initi(:,3)) ) - (( (.21 *.5 + .029 *.9434) ./ (.5 +.9434) ).*initi(:,3));      

    %Po       
    a(:,1) = power (( (.5 .* initi(:,1) .*(1 - initi(:,3))) ./ ((.5 + .13 ).*(initi(:,1) + .0823)) ),3); % p_o

    %C
    r(:,1) = (( 1.11.*  a(:,1) + .02 ) .* (  initi(:,2) - initi(:,1) ) ) - ( .9 .*  power(initi(:,1),2)) ./ ( power(.1,2) + power(initi(:,1),2) );

    %Ce
    r(:,2) = - r(:,1) .*5.5; % Ce

    r = r';

end
```

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The problem is either specific to programming (there's a bug in your code) or to biology (you did not understand the process you want to simulate). I don't actually know the concept of calcium oscillation but no one can correctly answer your question for the moment. You should add your code, describe it, describe the output and explain why the output is different from what you expected. I vote to close for the moment and will retract my close vote when the question will be improved.

Comment: @Remi.b Is that okay now?

Comment: Yep, that seems to be answerable now. Good improvement +1.

Comment: A general programming tip: define your parameters beforehand instead of directly hardcoding their values in the function. I did not go through your code but it seems that you have incorrectly typed the value of a parameter. As it stands, this question is off topic.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is about coding and not really about the computational model of the biological system.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Can you please tell me which parameter has been coded incorrectly?

Comment: @nashynash It is difficult for me to look through. I just guessed that might be the case. You can try defining the parameters in the beginning of the code and then use them in the equations. Difficult to troubleshoot otherwise. Something like `a=1; r(1)=somefunction(a);`

Comment: @WYSIWYG - your not voting anymore..

Comment: @WYSIWYG I think you should have at least checked the  code and the equations before you make such a comment.

Comment: @AliceD That is the default line that comes if I select the custom close. Anyways this is clearly off-topic.

Comment: @WYSIWYG - oh really? Sorry then! It's an interesting post given my post at meta. I think this one is indeed across the line. Happy I could help on the brink of closure anyhow.

Comment: @nashynash This is not the right site for code-checking and troubleshooting. You should do that in stackoverflow. And I commented based on my empirical understanding of systems and codes like these. Oscillations can disappear if some parameters change (Read about Hopf bifurcation). As I said, try to improve your coding style and you may find where you could have gone wrong. And it is better to write `0.5` instead of `.5`. General stuff.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Yes I know that it is more to do with the coding. But just wanted to try if someone from biochemistry would be familiar with Matlab and help me know where I am going wrong. But I will take you tip as well.

Ps: I have tried in stackoverflow, but since most of them are unaware of the mechanism behind calcium oscillations, they cannot fully grasp the idea.

Comment: @nashynash You are using the equations from a published study, right. So they should work: therefore I assume that the problem must be with the code. In stackoverflow, you need not explain calcium oscillation because your question is not really about if the model works (it works because it is already done by the people who published it. Your program is not replicating it). But before asking in SO try editing your code and examine if you have mistyped any parameter. Do the basic bug checks. You can try this site too: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Okay @WYSIWYG. And thanks for pointing out that page. Didn't know such page existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish to share an open-source modelling study on Ca<sup>2+</sup> oscillations in astrocytes which contains a detailed description of the underlying math and even better, it has supplementary Matlab code published alongside [(Zeng et al., 2009)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2770604/). This may be of help to check your formulae and script.

Unfortunately I do not feel inclined to start troubleshooting and bug-fixing your formulae and Matlab code, because, as mentioned in the comments, the issue can be *anywhere* in the chain of events.

**Reference**
[Zeng *et al., Biophys J* (2009); **97**(9): 2429–37](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2770604/)

Comment: @nashynash - good luck. I'm sorry to see this question closed after all the efforts you put into it. Perhaps you can try another SE and hope for better luck there.